GAMMS interaction between categorical and continuous factor on temporal trend in DV
I’m using the mgcv package in R to test questions from an experiment regarding non-linear trajectories in team performance. We’re primarily interested in between-group (experimental control) differences in within-team trajectories across the experimental scenario, as well as the moderating effect of a time invariant covariate with experimental condition.
Briefly, I have data on 40 teams (‘Team_ID’) of 5 people who completed a 900 second (‘Time’) firefighting computer simulation, where the primary objective is to protect human lives and environmental landmarks (e.g., houses, trees) by preventing the spread of active fires. We have self-reported data on 4 control variables (Game_Experience_mean + Team_Familiarity_mean + Ravens_mean + Trust_Propensity_mean) that we add to the parametric section of the model only. Prior to completing the simulation, we randomised teams to a control (‘Centralised) or experimental (‘Decentralised') condition (‘Condition’). We calculated a team performance score S, at a given time point (t) using approximately logarithmically spaced weights to different environmental features to provide participants with a defined hierarchy of objectives in the simulation (i.e., 10x civilians > 5x houses > 2x trees > 1x fields), relative to worst case scenario (essentially if there was no human action). So, we have 900 performance scores for each team across the entire simulation (‘Performance_Score’), where performance starts at 0 at time 0 and remains at 0 until around time 200’ish (where things with the simulation become complex, e.g., fires spread). For the primary analysis, I’ve selected the last 630 seconds for the estimation of performance trajectories, as it’s at this point where we experimentally added a disruption to the scenario.
See below for my final model. I believe this statistical representation is sound for my purposes, though happy to receive feedback if something seems off.
# contrast coded experimental condition for the analyses
df$Condition.ord <- as.ordered(df$Condition)
contrasts(df$Condition.ord) <- "contr.treatment"

bam_model3 <- bam(
  Performance_Score ~ Condition.ord 
  + Game_Experience_mean 
  + Team_Familiarity_mean 
  + Ravens_mean 
  + Trust_Propensity_mean   
  + s(Time, bs = "cr", k = 350)
  + s(Time, by = Condition.ord, bs = "cr", k = 300)
  # random intercept
  + s(Team_ID, bs = "re")
  # random slope
  + s(Team_ID, Time, bs = "re")
  # random smooth
  + s(Team_ID, Time, by = Condition.ord, bs = "fs", xt = "cr", m = 1),
  method = "REML",
  data = df
)

See below for a visualisation of bam_model3:

We’re also interested in testing the interaction between Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean (continuous variable) and Condition.ord (binary variable). Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean is measured on a 0-100 scale, whereas Condition.ord is a factor variable (two levels). Specifically, I want to test the moderating effect of Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean on the non-linear temporal trend of Condition.ord on Performance_Score, such that higher levels of Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean should bolster the non-linear temporal trend of Condition.ord on Performance_Score. Conceptually, I expect the Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean to exert a greater influence on Performance_Score for Decentralised team structures relative to Centralised structures.
I believe one option is to use te() as below:
bam_model4a <- bam(
  Performance_Score ~ Condition.ord 
  + Game_Experience_mean 
  + Team_Familiarity_mean 
  + Ravens_mean 
  + Trust_Propensity_mean   
  + s(Time, bs = "cr", k = 350)
  + s(Time, by = Condition.ord, bs = "cr", k = 300)
  + s(Team_ID, bs = "re")
  + s(Team_ID, Time, bs = "re")
  + s(Team_ID, Time, by = Condition.ord, bs = "fs", xt = "cr", m = 1)
  + te(Time, Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean, by = Condition.ord, 
       bs = c("cr", "cr"), k = c(40, 100)),
  method = "REML",
  data = df
)

An alternative option, which I read in an article by Coretta and Casillas (https://osf.io/8grj5/download/?format=pdf), is to create an interaction that I deploy within the bam syntax:
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    grpxtr = interaction(Condition.ord, Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean),
  )

bam_model4b <- bam(
  Performance_Score ~ Condition.ord 
  + Game_Experience_mean 
  + Team_Familiarity_mean 
  + Ravens_mean 
  + Trust_Propensity_mean   
  + s(Time, bs = "cr", k = 350)
  + s(Time, by = Condition.ord, bs = "cr", k = 300)
  + s(Team_ID, bs = "re")
  + s(Team_ID, Time, bs = "re")
  + s(Team_ID, Time, by = Condition.ord, bs = "fs", xt = "cr", m = 1)
  + s(Time, Time, by = grpxtr, bs = "fs", xt = "cr", m = 1),
  method = "REML",
  data = df
)

I’m new to GAMMs and mgcv, so am hoping I’ve provided enough information for you to help me figure out the best modelling approach. I believe everything makes sense to me up until I think about the moderating effect of our Condition.ord x Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean interaction.

You don't need all those random effect terms:
  # random intercept
  + s(Team_ID, bs = "re")
  # random slope
  + s(Team_ID, Time, bs = "re")
  # random smooth
  + s(Team_ID, Time, by = Condition.ord, bs = "fs", xt = "cr", m = 1),

The fs basis already contains random intercepts and random slopes of Time for each Team_ID for each Condition - or at least it would if you'd left m = 2 as the default. By switching to m = 1, you are making the overall smooth effects of Time have piecewise linear behaviour.
For this kind of difference smooth model, I would try to use the new sz basis:
bam_model3 <- bam(
  Performance_Score ~ Game_Experience_mean 
  + Team_Familiarity_mean 
  + Ravens_mean 
  + Trust_Propensity_mean   
  + s(Time, bs = "cr", k = K)
  + s(Time, Condition, bs = "sz", xt = list(bs = "cr"), k = K)
  # random smooths (+ intercepts + slopes
  + s(Team_ID, Time, by = Condition, bs = "fs",
      xt = list(bs = "cr"), m = 2),
  method = "fREML",
  data = df,
  family = SOMETHING
)

as an example for the first model. Note with "sz" you don't need the parametric group means. The first smooth of Time is an average smooth over all the data, while the "sz" basis smooth is a set of smooth differences from the average smooth, one per level of Condition.
This way you have something in the model for the differences between levels directly. You'd still need to follow up with an estimate of the differences themselves (either as you already have done or via the marginaleffects), to quantify the differences between levels.
You have the right idea to use a tensor product for the moderating effect of the other variable. The problem is that it isn't currently possible to fit tensor products with the "sz" basis.
As such, you could stick with the ordered factor approach (although these can be fickle and depend on the choice of the reference level you model first) or use a plain old factor by:
bam_model3 <- bam(
  Performance_Score ~ Condition
  + Game_Experience_mean 
  + Team_Familiarity_mean 
  + Ravens_mean 
  + Trust_Propensity_mean   
  + s(Time, bs = "cr", k = K)
  + s(Time, by = Condition, bs = "cr", k = K)
  + s(Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean, bs = "cr", k = K)
  + s(Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean, by = Condition, bs = "cr", k = K)
  + ti(Time, Team_Resilience_UN.0_mean, by = Condition,
       bs = rep("cr", 2), k = c(K,K))
  # random smooths (+ intercepts + slopes
  + s(Team_ID, Time, by = Condition, bs = "fs",
      xt = list(bs = "cr"), m = 2),
  method = "fREML",
  data = df,
  family = SOMETHING
)

where I've estimated main effects and pure interactions using combinations of s() and ti(), and I am using the normal factor Condition.
Some other comments:

Your choice of k seems excessive and as we expand the model for the different settings, you are going to be using a vast number of basis functions to estimate these effects. Carefully reconsider your choice of k for each smooth,

You need method = "fREML" at least for bam() to have any real effect on computational time and memory usage,

For a score that can't go below 0 you can't fit a Gaussian conditional distribution for the response as that distribution allows for negative values. Instead, you will need a distribution that has support on the non-negative real numbers. The only one in mgcv that meets this restriction is the Tweedie distribution, which you can fit with family = tw().

The idea of using an interaction via interaction() would be OK if you have two factors (although in that case we could stick with "sz" basis smooths and do something like
s(x) + s(x, f1, bs = "sz") + s(x, f2, bs = "sz") + s(x, f1, f2, bs = "sz")

to get the higher order interactions.
But for an interaction between two continuous variables you want a tensor product smooth, so in this case the interaction() idea doesn't work.



thanks for your insightful feedback @GavinSimpson, all of which makes sense.
